# Function to determine whether my Cart is empty?

Tags: commerce

I want to set an access callback on a menu item (primary links) for the shopping cart so that it only displays when there is something in the cart.  However, I can't find an obvious function to to this, and I don't know where to start with my own code.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same technique as [commerce_cart_block_view](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_block_view/DC) (thanks to Ryan Szrama for the assist!), you'll need to:

1. Get the order using [commerce_cart_order_load](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_load/DC), then check to see if there are no line items.
2. Apply the [entity metadata wrapper](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/DC) to retrieve further wrappers for the entity properties
3. [Count line items](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_items_quantity/DC) in the cart, filtering for products only

For the access callback itself, take a look at [Do you have an example of hook_menu() access callback?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/do-you-have-an-example-of-hook-menu-access-callback) for several examples and links to documentation.

Therefore, the callback should be something like:

```
function MODULE_access_check() {
  global $user;
  if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid)) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    return commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types()) > 0;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can't do a simple count on the commerce_line_items field, because it may still contain a reference to a non-product line item. Check out commerce_cart_block_view() in commerce_cart.module to see how I determine if the cart is empty for the purposes of showing the empty cart block vs. the cart block view.

Comment: Excellent point, much appreciated! I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for all your work on DC!

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm working on my first Commerce site and am super impressed at how it leverages all the goodness of Drupal that I (nearly) understand.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this patch [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2372223) then you can call `commerce_cart_is_cart_empty()` from your code:

```
if (!commerce_cart_is_cart_empty()) {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you might want to check the args, to avoid presenting the user with an access denied page when they remove the last item from their cart:

```
function MODULE_access_check() {
  global $user;
  if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid)) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $items = commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());
    return $items > 0 || arg(0) == 'cart';
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```