# If Drupal Commerce Cart is not Empty, add a class to body

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I'd like to add a class to body if the current user's cart is not empty.

I'd like to take the preprocess approach and not using rules.

so far using [commerce_cart_order_load](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_load/DC) function I came up with this in template.php:

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    global $user;
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);

    if ($order != 0) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'cart-loaded';
    }
}
```

but unfortunately it throws an unknown error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this [resource](http://www.drupalfoo.com/drupal-commerce-check-existence-productid-cart-programmatically) and thanks to @rémy I come up with this solution:

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    global $user;
    $cart = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
    foreach (entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $cart)->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
      if (in_array($line_item_wrapper->type->value(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'cart-loaded';
      }
    }
}
```

> So after a while of testing I ended up with an error with anonymous
>   users, so I digged a little bit deeper and come up with something new
>   and no errors this time:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    global $user;
    $quantity = 0;
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
    if ($order) {
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
        $line_items = $wrapper->commerce_line_items;
        $quantity = commerce_line_items_quantity($line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());
        if ($quantity) {
            $vars['classes_array'][] = 'cart-loaded';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using rules you would probably need to install context and context_rules module .., see here [Is it possible to add css class to the page's body tag with rules when certain conditions are met?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70741/is-it-possible-to-add-css-class-to-the-pages-body-tag-with-rules-when-certain-c)

So i would go with this approach: [Function to determine whether my Cart is empty?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90576/function-to-determine-whether-my-cart-is-empty)

But doing it in preprocess html like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700838/adding-a-class-to-body/7700886

If you're using ajax cart (fe with [dc_ajax_add_cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_ajax_add_cart)) you'll need to write some javascript too ..

Comment: I am actually using dc_ajax_add_cart module, Also I rather take the preprocess approach, based on what you referred so far I came up with this so far:
`function THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    global $user;
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
    
    if ($order != 0) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'cart-loaded';
    }

}` 
but it throws an unknown error, can you help me out

Comment: @Sohail Any reason you've left all of that vitally important information out of your question?

Comment: Hey @Clive , You are right, I guess it's been a while for me and forgot how to behave on stackexchange, I'll update the question right now, thanks